# Range decimal ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, range, decimal

I have the following declaration:

```
    [Range(0.00,1.00)]
    public decimal ConfidenceLevel { get; set; }
```

and view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfidenceLevel, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

in result I have the following:[image]

but I want to have like this: [image]
(with up/down arrows)

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `htmlAttributes` in a Razor text box.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfidenceLevel, new { @class = "form-control", type = "number", min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.01 })
```

But I have experienced situations where it does not display in all browsers. So mileage may vary